# How to Use Google Analytics Tracking for Links Targeting an iframe on a Page

Tags: iframe, google-analytics

First, [this page](http://www.newhavendisplay.com/app_notes.html)  is the one that I am working on getting specific tracking data for from Google Analytics. There is a Google Analytics account setup for this domain that tracks activity across other pages and sub-sites.

The navigation is categorized into various sub-navs that contain the links. These links target an iframe on the page where the content (pages) are loaded, as you can see in the source of the linked page. Currently, information on which links of the nav are most visited by users is not being collected, clicking those links does not seem to register as a separate or specific "session" with Google Analytics. The only information tracked is visits to the `index.php` home "landing" page.

**I would like to collect tracking data on which links in the navigation on this page are most often visited by users.** I've tried creating a new Google Analytics 'Account' and 'Property' with the iframe's root url and it still only tracks visits to the landing page.

How can I utilize Google Analytics on this page's iframe/navigation structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iframe tracking is very difficult, because an iframe is essentially a window to another place on the internet; a window that Google Analytics can't see.
In this case, since the iframe references a different part of your own website, you don't have the usual problems of cross-domain tracking. However, you still need to explicitly track the inside of the iframe.

You should be able to solve this by putting Google Analytics tracking code on all of the pages that can be loaded inside the iframe.

However, you will find that there are two problems; firstly you'll be immediately firing two page-views upon loading the page (which will ruin your Bounce Rate), and secondly Google Analytics will assume a linear path of pages, based on the page loads. So if you load pages B and C in sequence within an iframe on page A, Google Analytics will assume that you travelles A -> B -> C.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write an answer.

So this would affect the overall bounce rate of our domain? Or could we weed out the views that were multiples based on the iframe structure?

Visits to the page containing the iframe aren't so much our concern as which links users are choosing to navigate to within it. But if it adversely affects the data of the whole domain then it may not be plausible.